# Solving $ \frac {1}{\sin \theta} + \frac {\sin \theta}{\cot \theta} = 2 + \sqrt 3 $

Tags: trigonometry

> I need to find the value of $\theta$, where $0<\theta < 90^\circ$, such that
> $$ \frac {1}{\sin \theta} + \frac {\sin \theta}{\cot\theta} = 2 + \sqrt 3 $$

I've tried solving it as a quadratic equation. I've also tried to multiply both sides by 1/2, that'd make 2+$\sqrt3$ to be 1+$\sin 60$. But it's always ending up too complicated. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Are you sure that it is $$\dfrac{\sin}{\cot }$$?

Comment: **If** there is a typo, and the problem should be $\frac{1}{\sin \theta} + \cot \theta = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ then I would say that this is an ugly trick problem that trigonometry students are not trained for, and the problem composer's intent is that you solve the problem through trial and error against known *special angles*.  However, if there is no typo, then it is unclear to me what the problem composer is intending for the **trigonometry** student to do.  Personally, no way could I have ever attacked such a problem successfully when I was studying trigonometry.

Comment: Additionally, the equation (as given) has *two* solutions for $0<\theta<90^{\circ}$

Comment: @JoshuaWang Do you mean with or without the supposed typo correction?

Comment: If it is $\cot(\theta)$, using the tangent half-angle substitution would lead to a polynomial of degree $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Using the   tangent half-angle substitution $\theta=2\tan^{-1}(x)$*

If the problem is

$$\frac {1}{\sin (\theta)} + \frac {\sin (\theta)}{\color{red}{\cot(\theta)}} = 2 + \sqrt 3$$ it would be necessary to solve for $x$
$$\frac{x^6+x^4-8 x^3-x^2-1 } {2x(x^4-1)}= 2 + \sqrt 3$$ that is to say a sextic polynomial !

If the problem is

$$\frac {1}{\sin (\theta)} + \frac {\sin (\theta)}{\color{red}{\cos(\theta)}} = 2 + \sqrt 3$$ it would be necessary to solve for $x$
$$\frac{x^4-4 x^2-1 } {2x(x^2-1)}= 2 + \sqrt 3$$ that is to say a quartic polynomial ! You could solve with radicals but the solutions are so ugly that [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B-1+%2B+%284+%2B+2*Sqrt%5B3%5D%29*x+-+4*x%5E2+%2B+%28-4+-+2*Sqrt%5B3%5D%29*x%5E3+%2B+x%5E4%3D%3D0%2Cx%5D) only produces the numerical solutions.

Then, plot the function and locate visually where are more or less the roots. As said in comments, both equations produce two real roots for $0<\theta < \frac \pi 2$.

Comment: I don't know if the question might be wrong.. Can you tell me the numerical solutions you got from wolfram alpha? Thanks..

Comment: @A387. Click the link